Magento2 & Elasticsearch 8.13.4 install: Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. Unknown 401 error from Elasticsearch null
Installing locally using

php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --backend-frontname=admin --search-engine=elasticsearch8 --elasticsearch-host="https://localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200 --elasticsearch-enable-auth=true --elasticsearch-username="elastic" --elasticsearch-password="[my password]"

localhost:9200 returns
{
  "name" : "DULLAHAN",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "XA24SRmzTgaeIMbASp64rg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.13.4",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "zip",
    "build_hash" : "da95df118650b55a500dcc181889ac35c6d8da7c",
    "build_date" : "2024-05-06T22:04:45.107454559Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.10.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

so elasticsearch 8 should be running...
I could not find examples of this error occuring on these versions of Magento & Elasticsearch. How do I troubleshoot this one?

Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/72131091/11908692

Thanks! Tried, problem persists...

I recently faced and resolve the elastic search error.
Please follow these step one step may fix your issue , it will be working fine.
Step 1 : Configuartions of the elastic search https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-elasticseach-in-magento-2.html

Step 2: Reintsall the elastic search on your machine and install the compatible version with your Magento version.

Step 3: After reinstalling the elastic search , check the status of that, if not working then start the elastic search.

I think these steps will definitely resolve your issue.
If not please let me know.

In my experience, Magento does not work correctly with Elasticsearch 8+. I faced this issue before and downgrading to Elasticsearch 7 resolved the issue. Take care that you can't actually downgrade Elasticsearch, you will have to delete it and then reinstall Elasticsearch 7. An alternative would be to use a ready docker image with the version you would like to use.

It looks like you're having trouble getting Magento to work with Elasticsearch 8 even though Elasticsearch seems to be running fine. Here’s how you can troubleshoot and hopefully resolve this issue.
Steps to Troubleshoot and Resolve:
Check Elasticsearch Configuration:
Since Elasticsearch is running on https://localhost:9200, make sure it’s actually accessible. You can do this by using curl or your browser.
Verify that the username and password you provided are correct.
curl -u elastic:[my password] https://localhost:9200

Magento Configuration:
Ensure the values you’re passing during setup are correctly formatted, especially for Elasticsearch.
--elasticsearch-host="https://localhost"

Try using localhost without https and specify the port separately:
--elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200

Elasticsearch Authentication:
Make sure Elasticsearch is properly configured to use authentication. Check your elasticsearch.yml configuration file for authentication settings.
Confirm that the user elastic has the right permissions.
Magento Setup Log:
Check Magento’s setup logs for detailed error messages. These logs can be found in var/log directory under your Magento root.
tail -f var/log/setup.log

Magento Admin Configuration:
If Magento is already installed and you just need to configure Elasticsearch, you can do this from the Magento Admin panel:
Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search
Update the Elasticsearch settings there.
Reindex:
After ensuring Elasticsearch is correctly configured, reindex Magento:
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Example Command with Adjusted Parameters:
Try adjusting your installation command like this:
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --backend-frontname=admin --search-engine=elasticsearch8 --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200 --elasticsearch-enable-auth=true --elasticsearch-username="elastic" --elasticsearch-password="[my password]"

Final Check:
Once you’ve adjusted the command and settings, run the installation again. If it still doesn’t work, checking logs and verifying each step should help pinpoint where the problem lies.
Good luck! If you’re still stuck, feel free to reach out with more details, and we can dig deeper into the issue.
